Problem running/installing anaconda No module named ‘pluggy._result’ No module named ‘idna.package_data’ No module named ‘idna.package_data’
I had anaconda working properly on my machine, it started having some problems, I uninstalled it, cleaned it all. Now when I try to install it, I’m having multiple errors and I don’t know why.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pluggy._result’
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘idna.package_data’
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘idna.package_data’

Just by opening anaconda prompt.
And when I try to run conda
$ C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError(‘active_prefix_name’)

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]:

How to solve this? I tried installing module by module but it doesn’t work.
